# javafx.fxml.LoadException: Controller method "MyFunction" not found

Tags: event-handling, javafx-2

As described below, I Have an EventHandler linked to TextField (`text` variable), and I want to call a function from this handler that exists in the same class (MyFunction), so I'm getting the error (title of this post) :

**Code :**

```
class Example implements Initializable{
  //...
  public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {
    //...
    text.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER){

                MyFunction(text.getText());
            }
        }
    });
  //...
  }//function initialize ends here

  public void MyFuction(String text){
      //...
  }
 //...
 }//Class ends here
```

I'm using javaFX 2.2, I hope my request is quite clear.

Comment: Does your Example class implement javafx.fxml.Initializable? Is your "main class" Example class?

Comment: Yes, Sorry I have forgotten the implements part!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your FXML file. You are probably doing something like this: `<Button text="Button" onAction="#MyFuction"/>`while `onAction` handlers should accept single argument of a type that extends `javafx.event.Event`

Comment: I have found the problem, and it was very similar to what you have said. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to put `@FXML` in front of your `MyFuction()` method.

Comment: Nothing new after adding @FXML, Thanks!